# how do i fix door touching frame and hinge leaking

Tags: doors, door-frame

[[bottom part of door](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vR4zC.jpg)
][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vR4zC.jpg)
[image: full door]so i have this bathroom door which is hard to cloe. it is touching the door frame at the bottom and as you can see the pictue is of bottom hinge. my door frame is cracked from hinge and when i touch hinge i get black oil on my fingers. has hinge gone bad or someother issue? how do i fix it? any help would be appreciated
[image: door hinge]

So I observed middle screw of hinge just keeps on rotating.. it’s not fully fixed .. is it supposed to do so or it could be issue??

Comment: Please clarify where does the door hit the jamb/frame, the top or the bottom part or from top to bottom.  Please take clear picture(s).

Comment: I attached pictures here for full door and lower part of door. .. any advise

Comment: So I observed middle screw of hinge just keeps on rotating.. it’s not fully fixed .. is it supposed to do so or it could be issue??

Comment: Have you checked my edited and improved answer in regard to  a few things?  Check hinges and make sure they are fully seated/fit, secure middle screw on all hinges with long screw all the way to the studs on the wall.   Check paint as to how thick it has been rolled on the door thickness/depth.

Answer (score 1):

You need a picture of the door closed.  You need to examine the reveals, the space between the door and the jamb.  Is it tight in one corner and open in the opposite?

If the door is too close to the strike side (latch), you spread the hinge to pull the door back to the hinge side.  If the door is too close to the hinge side you pinch the hinge.  Generally this is the problem.  There could also be settling of the jamb with respect to the jamb and door.  Again pictures would be needed.  If the frame has settled around the door then you can use a sander to sand down the top or side of the door.  I recommend an orbital sander.  Sometimes you use both techniques together.

[Funny carpenter](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZcDj6g2UODw) does an easy to digest method to fix this

[Gary Katz](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=48fFtKTGTEw) has a more technical video.

Comment: Hey buddy.. I attached pictures … any advise budy

Comment: It is clear in the image that the reveal on the strike side top jamb is tight but the hinge side has clearance.  The hinge side reveal looks fairly consistent.  In this scenario I'd belt sand or orbital sand the top of the door.  Possible the door frame settled on the strike side, you could run a level but even if it did the simplest thing is to sand the top of that side of the door.

Answer (score 1):

In the closeup of the hinge, it's not clear that the hinge is seated properly in the jamb mortise. It should be flush. If it isn't, pull the hinge pin to separate the leaves and get the leaf properly set into the mortise on the jamb. You might need to cut a tiny bit of fuzz or paint with a utility knife. Then tighten/reassemble.

Replace the spinny middle screw with a 3" screw and drive that solidly into the framing.

If this doesn't fix things, then consider bending hinges, a-la Gary Katz.

Oil-wise, just wipe the hinge clean periodically. Someone dumped too much lube on it in the past.

Answer (score 0):

Unscrew the hinge and bring it to the store to get the right size and clean no oil driping.

Also bring the screws and get some that are about 1/4 inch longer.

Over time the screws loosen and the door is out of aligment. New longer screws can fix that.

There is not much you can do to repair the cracked door frame. other than hide it with some paint.

Answer (score 0):

Looking closely at that hinge in your picture; something is wrong with it.
Top of hinge (length A) is longer than the bottom (length B). It couldn't be the camera angle....?

Bottom of the hinge is not fully seated in the frame/jamb ( location C).

Check to see if all the hinges are strange like that.  Nonetheless, it needs to be corrected.

There is also much more paint on the door itself, which most likely is the same on the striker side of the door, it's right side.

Defective hinges, uneven, and not properly seated is certainly obvious and needs to be corrected.

And check the layers of paint ( location D) on the door depth/thickness especially on the handle striker side of door.

Compare these lengths:

A to B

X to Y

T to L

Hope this helps.
Take care.

[image: Hinge dimensions]